# Alterar cor de fundo de TD ao clicar RadioBox Checked e mudar de Cor novamente ao Sair do RadioBox

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde,

Gostaria de saber como fazer para mudar a cor de fundo de uma TD ao clicar no radiobox contido nela e ao sair para outro radiobox de outra TD voltar para a cor de fundo original

Estou tentando com o seguinte código em Jquery abaixo:

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.td_data_consulta', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().css('background', '#90EE90');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.hr_consulta').css('background', '#90EE90');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().css('background', 'white');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.hr_consulta').css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
```

```html
    <table class='table table-responsive table-hover table-condensed' id='table_horarios_consultas'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Data</th>
          <th>Hora</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' class='td_data_consulta' name='marc_data_consulta' id='' value=''> </td>
        <td name=dt_consulta class='dt_consulta' id=''></td>
        <td name=hr_consulta class='hr_consulta' id=''></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Porém só muda de cor quando eu clico pela primeira vez, quando clico em outro RadioBox de outra TD a cor não volta para a anterior, permanece na cor que foi alterada ao clicar.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Agradeço, desde já.

[RESOLVIDO]

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```js
// Ao clicar em um input do type="radio" de class = td_data_consulta
$(document).on('click', '.td_data_consulta', function() {
    // Agora vamos passar por todos elementos tr de class = tr_marca_consulta, definindo um bg padrão (branco) 
    $('.tr_marca_consulta').each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','white');
    });
    // E agora definimos o elemento atual (mais proximo do radio) com o background #9AFF9A
    $(this).closest('.tr_marca_consulta').css('background-color','#9AFF9A');
});
```

Comment: Não utilize a área de pergunta para colocar as respostas. Se você consegui resolver, insira (se quiser) o código na área de respostas.

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é que você faça isso com classe :D

No CSS adicione:

```
.hr_consulta,
.hr_consulta .td_data_consulta { background: #FFFFFF; }
.hr_consulta.selecionado,
.hr_consulta.selecionado .td_data_consulta { background: #90EE90; }
```

No Javascript, substitua:

```
$(document).on('click', '.td_data_consulta', function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parent().css('background', '#90EE90');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.hr_consulta').css('background', '#90EE90');
    } else {
        $(this).parent().css('background', 'white');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.hr_consulta').css('background', 'white');
    }
});
```

Por

```
$(document).on('click', '.td_data_consulta', function() {
    $('.selecionado').removeClass('selecionado');
    if ($(this).is(':checked') ){
        $(this).closest('.hr_consulta').addClass('selecionado');
    }
});
```

Me dá um feedback se funcionar blz

Comment: Valeu Anderson, vou testar mais tarde e passo o feedback em seguida, obrigado!

Comment: Boa noite Anderson, não funcionou... :(

Comment: Poderia postar o HTML também?